# Is the support for apim.jwt_authenitcation.subscription_validation_via_km removed in WSO2 APIM 3.2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to follow https://medium.com/@shagihan/configure-auth0-as-external-oauth-provider-for-wso2-apim-3-1-0-4368aa2448e3 with APIM 3.2.0 and just noticed that the above config has no effect on APIM 3.2.0. Even if I set apim.jwt_authenitcation.subscription_validation_via_km to false I am still getting a subscription validation error as below,

```
{"fault":{"code":900908,"message":"Resource forbidden ","description":"User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed."}}
```

So just wanted to confirm whether this has been removed from APIM 3.2.0. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this property is now removed from APIM v3.2.0.

In APIM v3.2.0, we support Auth0 by default and using the admin portal you can configure the Auth0 as the key manager.Please check https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-auth0-connector/#configure-auth0-as-a-key-manager

In APIM v3.2.0 API subscription validation has become mandatory. API subscription details will come to the API gateway via the traffic manager. By going forward, JWT tokens will not contain any API subscription details or any WSO2 specific information.